# Model update_attributes method returning 'true', but not actually updating the attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Game model that has several params, among them: a integer parameter called 'turn' and an 'opponent' parameter. When a player joins a game, I want to update 2 attributes: (1) the attribute 'opponent', (2) the attribute 'turn').

I use the code below for this:

```
# in games_controller.rb
def update
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  owner = @game.owner.id.to_i
  @game.update_attribute(:opponent, current_user)
  @game.update_attribute(:turn, owner)
end
```

The problem is, while the opponent attribute does update, the turn attribute remains nil. When I play with this code in the console, `@game.update_attribute(:turn, owner)` returns `true`, but still doesn't update. Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Note: I do have turn in my game_params

Comment: When in doubt, try to log or output `current_user` and `owner` to check their values, to make sure it's problem with update, not with values themselves. 

Another thing is that unless you specifically set `id` as string in DB, `id` should be integer by default, therefore you don't need `to_i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating :turn and :opponent. In one case you use an id `owner.id`. In the other case you use the active record object `current_user`. I think :turn is not the id of the person but the associated model, so you should use `owner = @game.owner`.

You could also use a single update:

```
def update
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  @game.update_attributes(:opponent => current_user, :turn => @game.owner)
end
```

Comment: `update_attributes` trigger validation, which OP might not want

Comment: Hey! I tried this but at first it didn't work. Then I decided to remove the turn column from game, and then I re-added the column. Then it worked! Likely I made an error of some sort when I first added turn to the game model. Thanks!